# Запятые между днем недели, числом, годом и местом

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией.
*Во вторник, 8 сентября 2015 года в помещении ГБОУ СОШ №2044, расположенном по адресу: Дмитровское шоссе, дом 165Е, корпус 8 состоится встреча...(т.д.)*
Помогите с правильностью расстановки знаков препинания.
Интересуют запятые после "вторник", "сентября", "года".
Также интересуют знаки препинания в адресе — нужно ли двоеточие, нужна ли запятая после "корпус 8".
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> *Во вторник, 8 сентября 2015 года в помещении ГБОУ СОШ №2044, расположенном по адресу: Дмитровское шоссе, дом 165Е, корпус 8
>   состоится встреча...*

Корректно:

*Во вторник, **8 сентября 2015 года**, в помещении ГБОУ СОШ № 2044, **расположенном по адресу Дмитровское шоссе, дом 165Е, корпус 8**, состоится встреча...*

Comment: Спасибо, так и думал, что дата отделяется запятыми, и после адреса нужна запятая, раз есть двоеточие.

Comment: Да двоеточие-то как раз **необязательно** (хотя и возможно). См. ответ Грамоты.ру: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=276772

Comment: Хм, по той ссылке зато запятую забыли поставить. А, понял, там не нужно ни двоеточие, ни запятая!

Comment: А запятая после _"корпус 8"_ нужна для закрытия **причастного оборота** _"расположенном по адресу... корпус 8"._

Comment: Аа... То есть, если оборота нет, то запятая после двоеточия не нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, такие объявления обычно имеют следующий вид:

(1) Во вторник, 8 сентября,  в помещении ГБОУ СОШ №2044, расположенном по адресу: Дмитровское шоссе, дом 165Е, корпус 8 состоится встреча...

(2) 8 сентября, во вторник,  в помещении ГБОУ СОШ №2044, расположенном по адресу: Дмитровское шоссе, дом 165Е, корпус 8 состоится встреча...

Или дата, или день недели являются уточнением, обозначать год не имеет смысла, понятно, что речь идет о текущем годе.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с ответом Славы 1947. Только мне кажется, что двоеточие всё-таки требуется из-за слова "расположенном", которого нет в его примере ("в министерстве по адресу").

Comment: Shampar, Вы написали: "Убрал слова об отношении к другому ответу и утверждение о якобы пропущенном там слове". Почему же якобы?! В одном случае "министерство", а в другом причастие "расположенный". Мне кажется, что это влияет на постановку двоеточия. Пускай останется, как есть. В Вашей версии мой ответ получается неполным, т. к. не проясняет моего мнения о постановке запятых.

Comment: Вы предлагаете что-то изменить в Ответе Славы. И это называете полным Ответом. Дайте свою правку текста, и всё прояснится. И о «министерстве»... Как ни старался, я не увидел этого слова в Вопросе.

Comment: Про "министерство" в его ссылке на ответ грамоты под его ответом. Я сравнил тот случай из ответа с этим из вопроса.