# Что делать с отсутствием запятой в пятнице 13-го?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная

> Постоянно отмечали мы «Пятницы 13-го». Этот праздник не имел ничего
>   общего с мифом о дне неприятностей. Напротив. Однажды в пятницу 13-го
>   из больницы выписали мою подругу. Она была еще очень слаба и могла
>   только лежать на диване и тихонько улыбаться – ведь это было,
>   действительно, радостное событие! И мы решили отпраздновать его как
>   День радости жизни. Этот День просто пришёлся на пятницу тринадцатого,
>   и с тех пор много лет я устраивала всякий раз вечеринки.

Запятые вокруг "действительно" можно ль пережить?

А с прописными что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Постоянно отмечали мы «пятницы 13-го».*** [С маленькой буквы; в кавычках — ведь это "неожиданный", ненастоящий праздник; без запятой.] ***Этот праздник не имел ничего общего с мифом о дне неприятностей.* *Напротив, однажды, в пятницу тринадцатого, из больницы выписали мою подругу.*** [Объединила в одно предложение; изменила: только что было "13-го"; выделила запятыми: когда? — однажды, когда? — в пятницу тринадцатого.] ***И, хотя она была еще очень слаба и могла только лежать на диване и тихонько улыбаться, это было действительно*** [без запятых; можно даже заменить на *по-настоящему*] ***радостное событие!*** [Перестроила предложение, потому что возникало ощущение, что радуются ее слабости.] ***Мы решили отпраздновать его как День Радости жизни.*** ["Радость", думаю, можно и с большой; см.: [День Радости](http://www.aquarium.ru/discography/den_radosti_live.html) (альбом "Аквариума").]  ***С тех пор много лет подряд — именно по пятницам 13-го — я устраивала вечеринки.*** [Перестроила предложение.]

Мне видится так.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы так написала:

*Постоянно отмечали мы **«пятницы 13-го».** Этот праздник не имел ничего общего с мифом о дне неприятностей. Напротив. Однажды в пятницу 13-го из больницы выписали мою подругу. Она была еще очень слаба и могла только лежать на диване и тихонько улыбаться – **и** это было **действительно радостное событие!** И мы решили отпраздновать его как День радости жизни. Этот **день** просто пришёлся на пятницу тринадцатого, и с тех пор много лет я устраивала всякий раз вечеринки.*

1) **Пятница 13-го**

А зачем здесь запятая, отношения неоднородные.

2) ***Действительно*** лучше не обособлять. Как вводное оно используется при доказательстве чего-либо или при подтверждении ранее сказанного. Но до этого здесь не было речи о чем-то радостном.

Comment: «Пятница, 13-е» — американский кино-сериал ужасов. / https://riafan.ru/986059-pyatnica-13-e-pochemu-lyudi-boyatsya-etoi-daty-chto-sluchilos-v-etot-den-chego-nelzya-delat и сюда смотри: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D0%B8+13-%D0%B5+%D1%81+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8+%22%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2C+13-%D0%B5%22%3F

Comment: Посмотрела... Сочетание дня недели и числа можно по-разному обозначить. 1) Сегодня пятница, 13-ое. Это однородное перечисление "плохих координат", такое перечисление использовано в названии фильма. 2) Пятница 13-го. Здесь вообще Р.п., а тогда это несогласованное определение при существительном. И это общепринятое обозначение этого дня      https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пятница,_13  Обратим внимание,что в статье также использовано разное оформление

Comment: Шарончик, см. ответ Славы1947 (но без аргументации, но он здесь самый продвинутый): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417741/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc

Answer (score 0):

Знаю, что отвечать „бесперспективняк”, однако вопрос мне показался достаточно интересным, поэтому изложу свою точку зрения.

1. Обособление в данном предложении слова „действительно” может быть обосновано „вводностью” сочетания, то есть оно здесь имеет добавочный характер со значением связи мыслей в предложении. Но я всё же воздержался бы от использования подобных конструкций.
2. Что касается написания некоторых слов в данном тексте с прописной буквы, здесь, конечно, „намудрили”... Во-первых, я бы не сказал, что название данного праздника может быть употреблено во множественном числе, хоть и его составляющая имеет такую возможность. Для сохранения стилистики текста лучше употребить „Пятница 13-го”.
   Во-вторых, сочетание „этот день” уж точно не может быть совмещено с каким-либо прописным написанием, так как подразумевается именно календарный день, а не сам праздник. Единственным исключением могло бы стать сокращение полного названия праздника, однако здесь это, как мне кажется, неуместно.